# Telerik RadEditor: Overriding Media Manager 'Save'

Tags: telerik, media, radeditor, media-manager

Searched for a similar question but cannot find anything as yet.

I have a RadEditor set up and I would like to override the event after the MediaManager file upload finishes so I can get the file and process it as i like. The FileBrowser I am using already has a 'prototype' but this is not leading me anywhere. I'm thinking it will be a JQuery/Javascript calls but I can't seem to find anything on the Telerik website.

```
    Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.DialogControls.FileBrowser.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {

        this.set_insertButton($get("InsertButton"));
        this.set_cancelButton($get("CancelButton"));

        var previewer = this.get_previewerType();
        var previewerType = eval("Telerik.Web.UI.Widgets." + previewer);
        $create(previewerType, { "browser": this }, null, null, $get(previewer));

        this.set_filePreviewer($find(previewer));
        this.set_fileBrowser($find("RadFileExplorer1"));
        Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.DialogControls.FileBrowser.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
    },

    dispose: function () {
        Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.DialogControls.FileBrowser.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
        this._insertButton = null;
        this._cancelButton = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine the solution through http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/onclientpastehtml/defaultcs.aspx

On the OnClientPasteHtml i do the following:

```
    function OnClientPasteHtml(sender, args) {
    var commandName = args.get_commandName();
    var value = args.get_value();

    if (commandName == "FlashManager") {
        var object = document.createElement("object");
        Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.Utils.setElementInnerHtml(object, value);
        var movieObject = object.firstChild; 
        //object.firstChild.Movie //this is the url of the file just uploaded
        args.set_value('Write custom html here');
    }
    else if (commandName == "MediaManager") {

    }
}
```